# How to call a C++ program from Clojure so that the programs stays open?

Tags: c++, clojure

Let's say I want to call a C++ program from Clojure, like stockfish.
 If I execute stockfish from the terminal, it stays open and interactive until the command is quit.

However, if I call from Clojure, it just calls it once and closes it.

I have used the programs macro of the me/conch package, like this:

```
    user> (programs stockfish)
    user> (stockfish "uci")
    "Stockfish 030620 64 by T. Romstad ... \nuciok\n"
```

And the program stops. How can I get the process to stay open and to keep interacting until I tell it to quit?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem has a canonical solution in the Unix `expect` tool, which has been replicated in, for example, Perl's Expect module.  There might also be a Java version of Expect.  If so, it might be a more direct solution.

About conch specifically, the `README.md` at https://github.com/Raynes/conch presents two ways of invoking a program.  The first way is easy, but sends only one burst of standard input before closing the program, as you observed.  The second way will be harder to work with, but you can send more input whenever you want by writing to the process' standard-input, and recover output whenever you want by reading from its standard-output.  It's under the heading https://github.com/Raynes/conch#low-level-usage.  It looks like a thin wrapper around the Java process API, which you might as well use directly.